# Javascript variables not adding the result, variables are act as string why?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Why error ?

expected results = `1360000`

result = `1000000360000`

```js
<script>
function hitungJumlah() {
var jumlah = document.getElementById("pinjam").value;
var lama = document.getElementById("kembalinya").value;
var bunga = lama * 12/100;
var biaya = document.getElementById("biaya").value = jumlah * bunga;
document.getElementById("total").value = jumlah + biaya;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Because it's read your data as `string` use `parseInt()` function to make your data as Integer

Try with this

```
parseInt(jumlah) + parseInt(biaya)
```

Beacuse `1000000` and `360000` act as string . `+` is also used for concatination in `javascript`

Answer (score 1):

Because the `*` operator wont type coerce like `+` operator. Besides you may not have to use `document.getElementById()` all the time. You might simply do;

```
<script>
function hitungJumlah() {
  var  jumlah = Number(pinjam.value),
         lama = Number(kembalinya.value),
        bunga = lama * 12/100;
  biaya.value = jumlah * bunga;
  total.value = jumlah + biaya;
}
</script>
```

Though `parseInt()` and `Number()` have differences. While `parseInt("42*10")` would result 42, as a number object constructor  `Number("42*10")` would result a `NaN`.

So be careful playing with them.